# The default admin password Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

I have only one account on my windows 10, an administrator account with no password. What is the password for that? I use `runas /user:Administrator cmd` to elevate cmd.exe and it asks me the password.

Comment: You said there's no password?

Comment: Please clarify. "what is the password for an account without password" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Attempting to read between the lines - if there's no password set & you are trying to set up a function that requres a password, you cannot do it without assigning a password to the admin account. Blank is not a password.

Comment: The local `Administrator` account should only be used momentarily if locked out of a system and then immediately disabled afterward, as it's not a secure account to use. The best policy is to create two user accounts, one regular and one admin, using that admin account only to approve UAC. Many Windows users find this inconvenient, so the next best thing is to have a user account that is an admin account, but the default `Administrator` account should remain disabled.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but I image that those who did, did so because (1) you said “***an*** administrator account” when you seem to be talking about ***the*** ``Administrator`` account, and (2) you haven’t said what you mean by asking for the password of an account “with no password”.  Also, you mention the `runas` command without saying why.  Is that meant to give us background information, or are you having a problem with that command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to create an account in Windows 10 without password. You leave the password field blank and windows will accept this.

When you boot into the computer with one account present that has no password, windows 10 will understand and log you in without prompting for a password.

If you start the computer and never see a login screen or if you see one, but you can just press enter or click the arrow to get in, your password is blank.

The advantage is that on a computer with just 1 user, you never have to login, so turning on the computer allows you to use the computer quicker.

The disadvantage is that some functions DO require a password, and they cannot be used until a password is specified. For example, Remote Desktop into the computer requires a password, accessing a share does too.

In order to setup a password, press CTRL-ALT-DEL, choose Change Password.
It will ask for the old password, leave this field blank, and enter a new password twice, then change the password.

Additionally, do note, in Windows 7 and newer, there is a user called Administrator, that is not your own user. This user is disabled by default and you cannot login with this user. This user is only present to be able to do UAC. If it is your goal to login with this account, note that this is impossible and the Administrator account should not be altered unless you know exactly what you are doing or don't mind reinstalling windows.

Comment: I use runas /user:Administrator cmd to elevate cmd, is this incl. in the DO require categ.?

Comment: Your question (comment) is not clear. What exactly is “categ”?

Comment: @FatFrog you will be interested in using an alternate approach. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098101/how-to-open-an-elevated-cmd-using-command-line-for-windows

Comment: @FatFrog: Everything except a direct console login is in that category, and yes, this includes runas.

Comment: Thanks @LPChip , now I use <windows r> _cmd_ <ctrl shift enter>

Comment: @FatFrog I myself use WIN (open start menu) type cmd, press ctrl-shift-enter. :)